# how does hibernate/jpa detect whether the persisted entity has been modified from outside client/hibernate instance?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

how does hibernate/jpa detect whether the persisted entity has been modified from outside client/hibernate instance?
i.e.

1. find a record and persist an entity with its id and modify it
2. launch any DB client and modify or delete the record
3. try to save the entity

--
what will happen? will hibernate detect the update? will it merge the changed to persistent context/session ?

Comment: It depends. Does the entity/table have a version-column?

Comment: @Grim do you mean without optimistic locking nothing will work? ok, what will happen when try to save/flush the 1) entity ? ( it's record was updated/deleted from outside already)

Comment: No, I mean outside of transactions. JPA hold a entity fully loaded having the value 1234 but outside of any transaction. Then you connect to the db using a different client (sql-manager or ssh-session) and change the value to 123**5** **and** you upcunt the version-field of the same tuple to the current unix-timestamp. Then a Exception must be thrown if you store the entity.

Comment: @Grim yes, that's an optimistic locking exactly. What will happen if nothing of  version-field locking implemented?

Comment: Ok, so without a version field! Thanks for the explaination. Please do not get me offensive, what have you tried to answer the question yourself? I mean your case is a little bit seldom but valid. I am sure you are professional enouth to setup a little test-case. Anyway, from my experience hibernate works on plain vendor-specific sql queries only. So hibernate will solve it throu SQL, right? You can output this sql and you will notice that in the WHERE-clause there is only the primarykeys selected and not the contents of the cached-old-values. Most sql-drivers report the effective update-rows.

Comment: @Grim, I saw many jpa  generated queries in console and update by id there. Does it mean hibernate overwrite the outside changes?

Comment: Yes! Dose this solve your question?

Comment: @Grim, yes, if only it's true ) generally, I heard many times just to make an experiment and get the answer. The problem is the experiment easily could be wrongly conducted (i saw a dude here whose experiment "proved" mysql doesn't have ACID )))) ). I'd like to see an answer reviewed by number of professionals with high reputation

Comment: Yes, maybe someone will contribute to this question aswell to give more a collective character of this question (since only me is answering is not very collective). I saw also mysql is not acid when the database is corrupted in example, or simply has a bug. The real thruth is inside the sourcecode of hibernate, the driver and the vendor-database. But who will ever reat all this and contribute to this question? What you can see are the sql-queries that are shot against the database. You can implicate conclusions because the where-clause not affect other columns than the PKs. Hope it helps.